# Use IF statement within a calulated field

Tags: sql, t-sql, if-statement

I am trying to determine all sales within the current financial year and wanted to incorporate an If statement as a calculated field to do so. Please see my code below.

```
        SELECT        RtnUserId, COUNT(*) AS Returns_, RtnDt, COUNT(RtnDt) AS DtRet, 
            IF 
                BEGIN

                YEAR(RtnDt) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(RtnDt) >= 4 

                RETURN 'INDATE'

            END       as Financial_Period

        FROM            dbo.vw_AN_Admin_VendorReturns
        WHERE        (RtnUserId = 'BEND1') OR
                        (RtnUserId = 'DEENA') OR
                        (RtnUserId = 'RICHARDK2')
        GROUP BY RtnUserId, RtnDt, 

            IF 
                BEGIN
                YEAR(RtnDt) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(RtnDt) >= 4 

                RETURN'INDATE'

            END
```

Comment: You want a CASE expression.

Comment: Hi, I've been able to use the CASE method, however I wanted to see if it was achievable using IF as a calculated field

Comment: You can't use it in a select statement, but you can create a user defined function and use that in a select statement.